# Define class members in a simple/minified way

Tags: typescript, angular

I have pretty big class definition with ~15 fields in my Angular 2 project.

```js
class Employee {
    private id: number;
    private name: string;
    private department: string;
    private title?: string;
    // 10 more fields 

    constructor(_id: number,
                _name: string,
                _department: string,
                _title: string
                // 10 more input parameters
                ) {
        this.id = _id;
        this.name = _name;
        this.department = _department;
        this.title = _title;
        // 10 more assignments
    }
}
```

This looks and works correctly, but with all 15 fields it's getting ridiculously long: **3 lines** per each class member.

Is there a way to simplify/minify the definition and still be able to create an object using `new`? Like this:

```
let person1 = new Employee(1, 'Andrei', 'Dev', 'Developer')
```

**Update**: I found a solution.

```
class Employee {
    constructor(private id: number,
                private name: string,
                private department: string,
                private title: string
                // 10 more input parameters
                ) {
    }
}
```

When declaring an input for `constructor` with access specifier (`public` or `private`) it does two thing:

1. Creates a member variable
2. Assigns an input value

I've never seen it in the official **Typescript** docs which is weird.

I found it in **Angular 2** docs https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/forms.html. However, I doubt, that it's related specifically to Angular2.

**Update2**: More complete and up-to-date *Typescript* documentation https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#8.3.1 (thanks to torazaburo)

Comment: There's probably nothing that will be less verbose, as for simplying, well that's a matter of taste.  You can have the ctor accepting a single parameter which is an object matching a specific interface who describe all of these parameters. You can also use the builder pattern.

Comment: @NitzanTomer, but then the caller (where I create an object) will be more verbose. How to use `builder` pattern here?

Comment: It's right here in the spec: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#8.3.1

Comment: @torazaburo, thanks for the new source of info. I didn't know about it. I usually use https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to add an access specifies (`private`, `public` or `protected`) in front of variables in constructor:

```
class Employee {
    constructor(private id: number,
                private name: string,
                private department: string,
                private title: string
                // 10 more input parameters
                ) {
    }
}
```

It does two thing:

1. Creates a member variable
2. Assigns an input value

I've never seen it in the official **Typescript** docs which is weird.

I found it in **Angular 2** docs https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/forms.html. However, I doubt, that it's related specifically to Angular2.

More complete and up-to-date *Typescript* documentation https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#8.3.1 (thanks to torazaburo)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if the builder pattern will do it for you in this case, but again, it's individual taste:

```
class Employee {
    private id: number;
    private name: string;
    private department: string;
    private title: string;
}

class EmployeeBuilder {
    private _id: number;
    private _name: string;
    private _department: string;
    private _title: string;

    id(value: number): EmployeeBuilder {
        this._id = value;
        return this;
    }

    name(value: string): EmployeeBuilder {
        this._name = value;
        return this;
    }

    department(value: string): EmployeeBuilder {
        this._department = value;
        return this;
    }

    title(value: string): EmployeeBuilder {
        this._title = value;
        return this;
    }

    build(): Employee {
        let employee: any = new Employee();

        employee.id = this._id;
        employee.name = this._name;
        employee.department = this._department;
        employee.title = this._title;

        return employee;
    }
}
```

Then you can build an instance like so:

```
let employee = new EmployeeBuilder()
                    .id(100)
                    .name("name")
                    .department("department")
                    .title("title")
                    .build();
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20Employee%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20private%20id%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20private%20name%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20private%20department%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20private%20title%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20EmployeeBuilder%20%7B%0D%0A%09private%20_id%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20private%20_name%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20private%20_department%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20private%20_title%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%09id(value%3A%20number)%3A%20EmployeeBuilder%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09this._id%20%3D%20value%3B%0D%0A%09%09return%20this%3B%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%09name(value%3A%20string)%3A%20EmployeeBuilder%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09this._name%20%3D%20value%3B%0D%0A%09%09return%20this%3B%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%09department(value%3A%20string)%3A%20EmployeeBuilder%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09this._department%20%3D%20value%3B%0D%0A%09%09return%20this%3B%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%09title(value%3A%20string)%3A%20EmployeeBuilder%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09this._title%20%3D%20value%3B%0D%0A%09%09return%20this%3B%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%09build()%3A%20Employee%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09let%20employee%3A%20any%20%3D%20new%20Employee()%3B%0D%0A%09%09%0D%0A%09%09employee.id%20%3D%20this._id%3B%0D%0A%09%09employee.name%20%3D%20this._name%3B%0D%0A%09%09employee.department%20%3D%20this._department%3B%0D%0A%09%09employee.title%20%3D%20this._title%3B%0D%0A%09%09%0D%0A%09%09return%20employee%3B%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20employee%20%3D%20new%20EmployeeBuilder()%0D%0A%09%09%09%09%09.id(100)%0D%0A%09%09%09%09%09.name(%22name%22)%0D%0A%09%09%09%09%09.department(%22department%22)%0D%0A%09%09%09%09%09.title(%22title%22)%0D%0A%09%09%09%09%09.build()%3B))

Comment: It's even longer, but I do get the idea. Looks interesting. Thanks. btw, I found solution.

Comment: Oh, I did not mention the using of the public/private/protected in the ctor params because I did not understand you correctly. My bad.

Answer (score 2):

You can make them like this. `?` will make them optional when creating with `new` keyword

```
export class Dragon {
    constructor(
        public id: number,
        public name: string,
        public details?: string,
        public skill?: string,
        public imageUrl?: string,
        public abilites?: string[]
    ) { }
}
```

Now you can make a new object like without giving all the fields

> `dragonObject: Dragon = new Dragon(1, 'Drogon');`

If you replace `public id: number` with `public id?: number` this And  `public name: string` with `public name?: string`

Now the object creation will be as simple as `dragonObject: Dragon = new Dragon();`

Comment: How do I specify `imageUrl` without specifying the previous properties?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of passing in ten parameters, pass in an object, the properties of which can then be assigned *en masse* onto the instance using `Object.assign`:

```
class Employee {
    private id: number;
    private name: string;
    private department: string;
    private title: string;
    // 10 more fields 

    constructor(obj) {
      Object.assign(this, obj);
    }
}
```

By the way, defining a property with a question mark as `private title?: string` is invalid syntax. That's for interfaces or parameters, not members.

For type-safety, define an interface for an employee-like object:

```
interface IEmployee {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  department: string;
  title?: string;
  ...
}
```

Then write the class as

```
class Employee implements IEmployee {

  constructor(obj: IEmployee) {
    Object.assign(this, obj);
  }
```

Now to create a new employee

```
new Employee({
  id: 22,
  name: 'Bob',
  department: 'HR'
});
```

and your object will be type-checked against `IEmployee` for valid/missing properties.

This also has the advantage that you can easily clone employees:

```
new Employee(otherEmployee)
```